# Random audio lecture in python not working : pygame.error: Couldn't open '48.mp3'

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, random, raspberry-pi4

Am a completely new on python, here is my problem am having,

I have a raspberry pi4b and I was making a script that will play an audio randomly. But the thing is i have tried everything that i can but its still not working and everytime am having this error message :
pygame.error: Couldn't open '48.mp3'

Here is the script (in python):

```
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

#in the folder where the audio files are, there are 150 audio files

playlist = ['001.mp3', '002.mp3','003.mp3','012.mp3','017.mp3','014.mp3','048.mp3']
pygame.mixer.init()
 
pygame.mixer.music.load(random.choice(playlist))
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.quit()
```

And this is the message am getting everytime (the random function seem to work but can't open the file)

```
pygame 1.9.4.post1
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/audio/TestAvecVlc.py", line 8, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load(random.choice(playlist))
pygame.error: Couldn't open '48.mp3'
>>>
```

Another one (we can see that this time its the file 012.mp3) :

```
pygame 1.9.4.post1
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/audio/TestAvecVlc.py", line 8, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load(random.choice(playlist))
pygame.error: Couldn't open '012.mp3'
>>>
```

I have also tried to rename the audio files and here again thats what am having :

```
pygame 1.9.4.post1
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/audio/TestAvecVlc.py", line 8, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load(random.choice(playlist))
pygame.error: Couldn't open 'fa.mp3'
>>>
```

As we can see here the random audio is correctly selected but still the same message :

```
pygame 1.9.4.post1
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/audio/TestAvecVlc.py", line 8, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load(random.choice(playlist))
pygame.error: Couldn't open 'ba.mp3'
>>>
```

I don't knwo what to do ....
Can someone help about this issue please ?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you confirm that the files are indeed mp3? Consider using `soxi` or a software of your choice.

Comment: I've download directly a mp3 format file, but yes the files are indeed mp3

Comment: The mp3 support is "limited" according to https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html You might want to check if you can load mp3 with e.g. `audioread`, perhaps use it instead to load data? Or convert all files. Some mp3 variants won't work with pygame.

Comment: Can you give me a little exemple on how to proceed pls  :))

Comment: I just gave you a few options. Are all of them OK? Is converting all of the files to e.g. WAV an option?

Comment: I have tried usuing the wav format even the ogg fomat and still having the same message : pygame.error: Couldn't open 'ba.ogg'  - pygame.error: Couldn't open 'ba.wav'; let me try with audioread and will be back in some hours...

Comment: Still the same nothing change ....

Comment: Then I am pretty sure there's something wrong with the files. Share a link to one.

Comment: here is the link for the fa.mp3 : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hm4ImZhtAezfNxHBgD-BKEoCWsZW3UjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: and the link for the ba.mp3 : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HC2hK-FDZzrC01gSvc_ccY62tAzcOpEZ/view?usp=sharing